# Websockets with flask/uwsgi/nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, websocket, uwsgi

I have this problem that i'm developing a flask api and need to add just 1 websocket call, i had tried wit 3 different python packages but i had no luck

```
from gevent.monkey import patch_all
patch_all()
# pylint: disable=wrong-import-position
from flask_uwsgi_websocket import GeventWebSocket  # noqa: E402
# More imports...
# pylint: enable=wrong-import-position

app = Flask(__name__)
websocket = GeventWebSocket(app)

# A lot of @app.route('/routes')


@websocket.route('/api/websocket/echo')
def echo(w_s):
    """Websocket"""
    print(1)
    print(w_s)
    print(2)
    while True:
        msg = w_s.receive()
        w_s.send(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, gevent=100)
```

That is my flask code that is inside a main.py file

```
[uwsgi]

app = main
module = %(app)
callable = app

socket = /tmp/module_name.sock
chdir = /path_to_module
chmod-socket = 666
virtualenv = /path_to_module/venv
enable-threads = true
http-websockets = true

master = true
processes = 1
die-on-term = true
```

That is my config-uwsgi.ini

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name some.server.com;

    ssl_certificate   /etc/letsencrypt/live/some.server.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/some.server.com/privkey.pem;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/module_name.sock;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
        proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
    }
}
```

And that's my config-nginx.conf file

I can access all the app.route's, but can not the websocket.route

I been searching and found that "Upgrade" thing in the HTTP headers, so added that to the nginx config file, all the time I can reach the endpoint but can not establish the connection, it closes almost immediately, and after added headers on nginx it just takes a little bit more to close but is not getting connected

```
Jan 09 22:23:25 ip-192-168-1-50 uwsgi[242836]: [pid: 242836|app: 0|req: 5/5] 189.XXX.XXX.XXX () {52 vars in 914 bytes} [Mon Jan  9 22:23:25 2023] GET /api/websocket/echo => generated 207 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 87 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

That's the result in the uwsgi log

Now i don't know what more to try, or where to search because, that is almost the same from the documentation example https://pypi.org/project/Flask-uWSGI-WebSocket/